# Exclude country from `occ_search` query using the `rgbif` package

Tags: r

Is it possible to exclude certain parameters in a `occ_search` query. I am looking to exclude a certain country. e.g.

```
occ_search(scientificName = "Abutilon grandifolium", georeferenced = T, country != "ZA" ))
```

Does the negation `!` work?

Comment: what library are you using? Can you also include a sample of your data using `dput(head(data))` and adding the output to your question?

Comment: thanks, I changed the example and question to mention the rgbif package